# I'm using pandas to delete first 9 rows but it is still keeping the first row

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas

###### Below is my code -

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df1 = pd.read_excel(str(sys_folder) + "Italy_SS304.xlsx")
df1.drop(df1.index[0:9], axis=0, inplace=True)
df1.drop(df1.columns[1:3], axis=1, inplace=True)

df1
```

attached image is my database from excel

[image]

Comment: have you tried using pd.read_excel's `skiprows` and `usecols` parameters?

Comment: range 0:9 is only 8 rows (until 9-1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While reading the excel, the first row is taken as header, unless you explicitly say it is not. You need to add `header = False` so that the dataframe does not take the first row as header.

Assuming you are writing `df1` back into an excel using something like `df1.to_excel()`, you will need to use the same `header=None, index=False`, assuming you don't want to add index.

Change the read_excel file to as shown below.

```
df1 = pd.read_excel(str(sys_folder) + "Italy_SS304.xlsx", header=None)
```

...and if you are writing back to excel, use the line like this (after the drop commands)

```
df1.to_excel('NEWFILE.xlsx', header=None, index=False)
```